# NULL or unique emails in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC 5 app and I want to allow users to have no email address set or, if they have one set then to ensure it's unique. Is there any easy way to do this using the built Identity provider or will I need to roll my own?

The issue I'm running into is if I set the property `RequireUniqueEmail = true` in my `UserValidator` then then I can't enter NULL emails. But if I set it to false then no uniqueness check is performed when adding an email.

Comment: Are you wanting client side validation of just server side?

Comment: I want to check that the email address is unique among the existing email addresses in the database, so it would be a server side check

Comment: OK, If you do want client side validation to check its unique then you could use the `[Remote]` attribute [refer this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(VS.98).aspx). For server side, I think you would just need to check if the string length is > 0 and if so do the database lookup

Comment: Uniqueness and allowing NULLs don't really go together. If 2 users have no emails, does that make the emails to be duplicate NULLs? You'll have to build the validation yourself in your controller when the users are created. There is nothing pre-built in Identity framework that will do this logic for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the answer is no. There is no built in way to do this.